# Can the administrator of an open group page on Facebook tell who views page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, statistics

Is it possible for an administrator of an open group page on Facebook to see if a non-member has been regularly clicking on the page and reading postings on the respective page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

I am an admin of an open, though small, group page on Facebook and I can't see that information.